# Show that the number $2^{2^n}+1, \ \forall n\in\{\mathbb{N}:n\geq 2\}$ has the last digit $7$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility

> **Problem:** Show that the number  $2^{2^n}+1, \ \forall n\in\{\mathbb{N}:n\geq 2\}$ has the last digit $7$ by induction and without using modular arithmetic.

---

I know how induction works and I've tried the basecase $n=2$ which holds true.

Setting $p(n)=2^{2^n}+1$ and computing $p(2)=17,$ which indeed has the last digit seven.

Now I need the inductive step, so I assume this holds true for a number $n=m\in\{\mathbb{N}:m>2\}.$ Our goal here is to verify that $p$ also holds for the following integer $n=m+1.$ Our induction hypothesis states that

$$p(m)=2^{2^m}+1=? \quad \quad (1)$$

Here is where I run into trouble. If the problem statement was to show that it's divisible by $7$, then in $(1)$ I could have set the RHS to $7k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and proceed. But in this case, I'm lost.

Comment: Hint: It may be an easier induction to show that whenever $k$ is divisible by four the power $2^k$ has six as its last digit .

Comment: That a number has last digit $7$ means that it is of the form $10k + 7$ for some integer $k$. Incidentally, that's exactly what modular arithmetic does; it just hides the "$10k+{}$" part of it behind $\!\!\!\pmod{10}$. So if you're going that route, then technically you are already using modular arithmetic.

Comment: @Arthur - Bingo! That's what I was looking for. I'm going to try and proceed by myself now.

Answer (score 6):

**Hints:**

1. $\;2^{2^{n+1}}=\bigl(2^{2^{n}}\bigr)^2$,
2. $6^2=36$.

Comment: I voted +1 because I think  it's right. In our forum there are number of professors, which down vote without any reason.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg of course it's right ...

Comment: +1 This "maniac" adjective is new here. Earlier I saw the use of the word "nefarious" by a user here and I also started using it for such downvoters. Will switch to the shorter word "maniac" from now.

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that $2^{2^n}+1-7$ or $2^{2^n}-6$ is divisible by $10$.

The base of induction is true.

Now, let $2^{2^n}-6$ is divisible by $10$.

Thus, $$2^{2^{n+1}}-6=\left(2^{2^n}-6+6\right)^2-6=\left(2^{2^n}-6\right)^2+12\left(2^{2^n}-6\right)+30$$
and we are done!

Comment: Very nice! (+1)

Comment: This is nice. But why do we need to prove that $2^{2^n}-6$ is divisible by 10? Is it because $$2^{2^n}+1=10k+7 \Leftrightarrow 2^{2^n}-6=10k?$$

Comment: Initially I downvoted. Your post had only the first line at that time, so it smelled of an attempt to get an early time stamp without having thought it through. I removed the downvote, when you fixed things. Mind you, I still like Bernard's take more.

Comment: @Parseval Yes! $2^{2^n}-6$ is divisible by $10$ by the induction assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You can state: assuming it is true for $n$:
$$2^{2^n}+1=A\cdot10+7$$
we show it is true for $n+1$:
$$2^{2^{n+1}}+1=(2^{2^{n}})^2+1=(A\cdot10+6)^2+1=A^2\cdot100+12A\cdot10+37.$$

Comment: +1 the square of a number that ends with 6 will always end with six ...adding 1 make it seven

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $2^{2^n}+1$ ends in $7$.

Then we have $2^{2^{n+1}}+1=2^{2^n} \cdot 2^{2^n}+1=2^{2^n}(2^{2^n}+1)-(2^{2^n}-1)$ and now because $2^{2^n}+1$ ends in $7$ we have that $2^{2^n}$ ends in $6$ and that $2^{2^n}-1$ ends in $5$ and the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

With $T(n)=2^{2^n}+1$ , we have the recursion

$$T(2)=17$$ $$T(n+1)=T(n)^2-2T(n)+2$$

The base case is clear

Assume $T(n)=10k+7$ for some $k$

Then $$T(n+1)=100k^2+120k+37=(10k^2+12k+3)\cdot 10+7$$ finishing the proof.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but read the problem statement before you reply. It specifically says "without using modular arithmetic".

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted because the question clearly asks to not use modular arithmetic.

Comment: I removed the downvote (and replaced it by an upvote), as you changed your answer.